# UAC get Token from Where?

Tags: windows, uac, administrator, runas

When a User try to run an application as Administrator they have two option, if they are belongs to administrators group they gone through YES or NO consent prompt. if they are standard user who doesn't have Admin Access they are asked for Admin User credentials which is CREDENDTIAL prompt.
when users go through second flow it is obvious that after getting username and password we can generate User Access Token. but what is case for first flow ? I know this user has filtered token but How & from where does the UAC get this non limited token ?

I did go through UAC flow which is from MSDN but this part not documented properly.

Comment: Not sure I get your point. TMBK the user session token for UAC privileged access is already generated during regular user login (so proactively two tokens, standard and privileged, are generated whenever a protected admin logs in). The privileged token is just inactive unless it gets activated by the UAC prompt.

Comment: When user login - token and logon session is created. If logon is interactive and user have administrators group in the token, and uac is enabled - created second, filtered token and logon session - system disable administrators group in this token - it exist, but with attribute for deny only. Remove some privileges from second token. This 2 sessions linked by self. We always can got linked token via TokenLinkedToken. But if you have TCB privilege you got it as primary token, otherwise as impersonation token with identification level - so for query only.

Comment: [TokenLinkedToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-token_linked_token) - consent.exe simply take token via this, if user confirm elevation

Comment: @Halfix we are on the same track, and yes you are right about two token creation and normal process does run in standard access token. but the activation part is where I am stuck. How does UAC get that inactive privileged token.

Comment: @RbMm I did look into TokenLinkedToken scenario, as you mentioned it is used to query the linked token handle, but some how consent.exe doesn't follow this method to get the privileged token handle.

Comment: no, the consent.exe ( in paire with appinfo.dll) exactly used TokenLinkedToken

Comment: I have the same question that I posted as a comment on your [other (possibly identical) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78006915): What's provoking the question?